# Cmake can't link glut library after system update

Tags: c++, cmake, glut

Before I update the system today, everything goes well.
My CMakeList.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.7)
project(p3)

# Set the C++ Standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Set the compiling flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Werror -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wvla")

# Find the OpenGL library
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Find the GLUT library
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Build
add_executable(p3 ...)
target_link_libraries(p3 ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} m)
```

But after the update, it goes wrong!
I have many errors when compiling:
(I use freeglut)

```
undefined reference to `glutInit'
ndefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
undefined reference to `glutIdleFunc'
undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
```

It seems like that cmake can't link glut library.
But other functions such as `glVertex2f` is fine.
And using `g++` to compile is also OK.
Now I have to change my CMakeList to this:

```
// ...
target_link_libraries(p3 ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} glut m)
```

After I add `glut` , it works again.
Why would this happen?
How can I fix it?

Useful Information:

```
cmake version 3.22.1
```

Comment: If you have CMake 3.22, there is _no earthly reason_ to set 2.7 as a minimum. I can nearly guarantee your project will not work as you expect with 2.7

Answer (score 4):

When use `find_package` for find some package, consult its documentation about what variables or targets it defines. Documentation for [FindGLUT.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGLUT.html) tells that the script defines variable `GLUT_LIBRARIES`, so for link with the GLUT you need to use that variable, other than `GLUT_LIBRARY` one.

If unsure whether you use a correct variable, then print its content. E.g. with

```
message("GLUT_LIBRARY: ${GLUT_LIBRARY}")
```

In most cases empty content of the variable means that you use **wrong variable**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expand package variables into directory commands! **Always, always, *always*** use **imported targets**.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(p3)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

add_executable(p3 ...)
target_link_libraries(p3 OpenGL::GL GLUT::GLUT m)
target_compile_features(p3 PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

It's simpler to write, read, and maintain.